# Write query better - as it is only working for only 1 row in notice date WITH CURDATE?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, triggers

CREATE TRIGGER NOTICE_ISSUE
AFTER INSERT ON MEMBERS
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO NOTICE (Ssn,LSSN,NOTICE_TYPE) VALUES
((SELECT Ssn from MEMBERS WHERE CURDATE() = NOTICE_DATE),
(SELECT LIB_SSN from MEMBERS WHERE CURDATE() = NOTICE_DATE),'RENEW YOUR MEMBERSHIP');

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/62576) You've posted nothing except an unformatted SQL statement. No database schema, no sample data, no explanation as to what is wrong with your existing SQL.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Please use the code formatting tool in the question editor - its unreadable as it stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are duplicating the select query, it would be better like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER NOTICE_ISSUE AFTER INSERT  
ON MEMBERS  
FOR EACH ROW  
INSERT INTO NOTICE (Ssn,LSSN,NOTICE_TYPE)  
SELECT Ssn, LIB_SSN, 'RENEW YOUR MEMBERSHIP'   
FROM MEMBERS  
WHERE CURDATE() = NOTICE_DATE
```